# Keeping original edge IDs in Output Feature from sDNA analysis?

Tags: qgis, sdna

I’d like to keep the original edge IDs for each link in processing a network with sDNA using the Integral Analysis function. I’m using the free version of sDNA in QGIS, and from what I understand, new edge IDs are produced in the Output Feature from the Integral Analysis function.

I'm processing a network derived from OSM and would like to keep the original IDs for further analysis.

Comment: Your question body currently contains no question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integral doesn't currently do this, however, unless you use the disable lines feature it should output exactly the same polylines as input, in the same order. So if you create a sequential field in the input data, and join the output on that field, you will be able to recover the original id even if not sequential.

Personally I just use spatial join when I need to join multiple outputs back to the input network - more computation but requires little effort from the user.

Comment: Great, this worked perfectly. I didn't realize the output lines are produced in the same order as the input lines (so long as the disable lines feature is disabled)! This is really great to know and will help with future use. Thought that I had read the user manual well enough. Will have to make it my tonights reading. Thank you

Comment: I don't think the user manual says so, nor have I thought about making this guaranteed behaviour. However I will file a bug noting that "original ID" field would be useful should this behaviour ever change.

Comment: That would be great, will keep an eye out for an update. Thanks SsB